# Bootstrap -Alienar contenido al centro, Pantalla horizontal-móviles

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un div con dos imágenes, al verlo en un celular se corría un poco a la izquierda entonces le coloque el offset-xs-1 y se ve bien, sin embargo, al rotar la pantalla y colocarlo se ve muy a la izquierda y no se centra , ¿alguien sabe cómo centrarlo cuando la pnatalla está rotada? tambien intenté con text-center.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11 text-center">
          <br>
            <div class="text-center slider-primary">
               <img src="img/men.jpg"  class="img-responsive img-presentation" alt="">
               <img src="img/avatarfemale.png"  class="img-responsive img-presentation" alt="">
            </div>
     </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a dejarle margenes a los lados y has que la imagen abarque el 100% del div que la contenga, mira te dejo un ejemplo de como quedaria....
Espero te sirva

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row>
   <div class= "col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
         <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 col-lg-10 text-center">
              <br>
                <div class="text-center slider-primary">
                   <img src="img/men.jpg" width="100%"  class="img-responsive img-presentation" alt="">
                   <img src="img/avatarfemale.png" width="100%"  class="img-responsive img-presentation" alt="">
                </div>
         </div> 
     <div class= "col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```